# PKI certs hierarchy

Tags: certificate, openssl, certificate-authority

I follow https://jamielinux.com/docs/openssl-certificate-authority/index.html and after create root and intermediate ca the chain file dosnt have hierarchy like other ca.

Here's the sample of expected hierarchy:

[image]

- Root ca creation
- Intermediate CA created and singed by root ca
- domain cert created and singed by intermediate.

Create https://jamielinux.com/docs/openssl-certificate-authority/create-the-intermediate-pair.html#create-the-certificate-chain-file

But after import `ca-chain.cert.pem` via firefox that contain intermediate and root (exactly this order) . Just import the intermediate.

[image]

[image]

After importing in browser website work well but there is no root ca in hierarchy. just intermediate then website certification.

Even after import root ca the cert doesn't hierarchy as i expected.
What i missed?

Root ca:

```
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number:
            f1:61:fb:1e:9e:12:3d:1a
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C = IR, ST = Tehran, L = Tehran, O = SampleOrg, OU = Infrastructure Unit, CN = SampleOrg Root Certificate Authority, emailAddress = iu@sample.tld.com
        Validity
            Not Before: Jan  1 00:00:00 2018 GMT
            Not After : Jan  1 00:00:00 2058 GMT
        Subject: C = IR, ST = Tehran, L = Tehran, O = SampleOrg, OU = Infrastructure Unit, CN = SampleOrg Root Certificate Authority, emailAddress = iu@sample.tld.com
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                Public-Key: (4096 bit)
                Modulus:
                    00:dc:20:86:ef:e7:01:fe:a8:6f:72:c1:b0:19:f3:
                    54:4c:36:f8:c9:c3:e9:82:58:e1:40:d0:dc:94:40:
                    7e:81:44:bc:83:a2:60:b0:60:b5:07:db:8a:23:ba:
                    21:d6:b6:9e:72:fd:03:86:6c:87:92:2c:f0:f9:4c:
                    64:e3:42:50:e4:93:ce:49:55:ce:c6:ce:cd:36:af:
                    2f:d2:f8:61:21:92:2e:67:0a:57:13:7f:e5:d6:a0:
                    42:1e:61:46:f2:c5:f3:0d:05:19:09:93:b5:7d:6b:
                    23:d1:a4:ae:9d:e4:22:9e:17:f5:b8:38:11:f6:f7:
                    29:6c:a1:7e:b5:68:34:9d:31:b8:cb:bd:b8:fb:9a:
                    25:f6:96:8b:6b:21:22:38:f0:a6:b4:5a:3a:00:94:
                    f4:de:2c:15:98:b1:82:8b:fa:f2:0e:e8:8e:2e:69:
                    86:0f:f6:f4:82:8d:b5:6f:00:8b:cc:3c:29:b8:2d:
                    fa:03:c2:7f:46:c5:0b:9f:4e:ee:f5:82:d5:b2:9f:
                    29:3b:43:b8:0b:90:05:f6:53:68:be:f2:d2:91:f9:
                    ec:5a:3f:83:d0:0f:49:6a:7f:d9:a3:72:d0:8f:74:
                    a6:4b:c8:31:bd:ac:45:6b:51:c4:46:0d:aa:31:3d:
                    03:bb:fc:7f:50:c6:ec:57:72:84:40:a8:4f:1d:14:
                    b6:4d:30:6c:2f:b1:69:7a:9b:1f:8f:f9:af:a3:00:
                    df:96:df:df:e6:b9:6d:5e:bc:1e:40:e7:ee:fe:18:
                    aa:bb:19:e5:26:9f:79:01:76:06:26:6b:43:cb:15:
                    41:aa:01:19:d9:11:19:7b:df:99:8c:68:8d:4b:a9:
                    76:3b:32:ff:68:4d:5c:0e:5d:c7:5f:ed:1a:20:f4:
                    68:29:0b:21:ac:79:05:9a:57:0a:54:d7:7d:06:83:
                    f9:b5:79:09:65:fa:c2:83:6d:b6:77:3e:e0:b2:ac:
                    15:b4:88:22:95:64:70:27:88:50:2b:e4:2e:6f:df:
                    f1:3c:fa:21:70:c2:bf:54:18:3e:2a:6f:2f:28:0f:
                    d3:83:61:6c:b5:9d:5e:4f:f8:8a:3b:75:ef:e9:97:
                    58:98:2f:31:39:cd:dd:18:ff:fc:ce:d0:83:72:23:
                    4f:e1:66:a4:0b:2a:5d:44:79:e4:7b:6a:67:d5:c5:
                    6a:a7:c9:ff:7e:1c:1b:20:e9:18:ee:69:cd:5b:cb:
                    f1:c3:cd:9e:62:38:f3:b0:f3:70:f8:0e:2f:c9:7b:
                    27:6e:5b:e4:78:b8:a2:b4:5a:26:ff:9f:bd:c6:b1:
                    2d:5b:a4:b3:49:17:24:68:02:be:b9:7e:c3:d5:37:
                    ca:c3:b4:bd:1b:28:fd:70:45:4f:9e:7e:1b:2a:14:
                    3d:cf:f9
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier:
                4B:E6:00:6C:EB:DF:D8:4E:AB:EB:86:48:A2:8D:BB:18:09:C4:B4:6F
            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier:
                keyid:4B:E6:00:6C:EB:DF:D8:4E:AB:EB:86:48:A2:8D:BB:18:09:C4:B4:6F

            X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
                CA:TRUE
            X509v3 Issuer Alternative Name:
                <EMPTY>

            X509v3 Key Usage: critical
                Digital Signature, Certificate Sign, CRL Sign
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
         8a:33:b3:59:6d:30:11:d1:df:71:fa:ed:90:02:13:40:84:e0:
         54:3e:88:ce:12:07:c9:29:ce:44:69:c0:e8:d4:90:e3:48:5c:
         0c:6d:4f:c4:d6:af:a3:c5:86:ff:d1:93:8f:9b:b3:5e:8f:37:
         fa:9c:93:cd:a8:0d:71:28:91:fa:06:17:70:a4:be:7a:30:b1:
         76:c3:33:f2:4b:a7:b8:ec:a7:f9:76:e9:08:cb:b3:1b:cd:a5:
         5f:c6:1a:85:7c:76:d4:67:da:d4:80:6d:be:80:4b:5c:f6:d0:
         f8:f5:47:12:73:92:35:86:f2:76:4f:82:2c:e9:ec:1b:bf:5b:
         cb:fa:31:65:41:ad:6f:e6:71:76:76:46:e7:51:b2:d0:fe:77:
         76:2f:49:9d:c2:79:7a:94:9b:a8:42:4e:91:bb:72:60:c6:91:
         e9:e6:cf:59:17:20:75:14:90:42:7c:c9:5d:27:10:b9:81:c0:
         a5:43:3d:0a:e0:c6:ba:7e:e9:9a:98:02:a6:bf:5d:55:2b:31:
         b9:0a:91:d7:f0:28:07:0b:80:e2:1c:0e:5f:c8:f8:88:17:3d:
         8b:b0:b3:df:09:e3:0d:4b:1c:ed:d9:d1:8a:9a:d8:d8:b0:e6:
         bf:9f:1e:14:86:45:47:5a:c5:e3:90:06:b7:0a:72:60:0d:0d:
         2c:bd:ce:19:57:02:09:e0:d8:6e:ed:9a:7e:d6:8d:18:42:fc:
         32:54:88:c1:87:98:0b:7e:ca:dd:9a:3e:d8:5b:00:91:28:ea:
         2b:35:ad:36:6c:9d:e0:cc:41:cd:e9:31:75:ec:2c:e5:5e:24:
         59:cd:f6:cb:14:42:e1:b6:30:84:6e:f2:13:8a:9e:32:0e:34:
         1a:4f:5d:a7:19:67:64:84:29:5f:ec:7e:18:1a:7f:0c:65:6a:
         04:8a:fa:a2:2b:76:ff:1f:c4:0a:5f:1b:df:4e:6b:60:58:ae:
         37:d8:b8:3b:09:fa:34:8e:6a:e2:1c:a5:c6:a5:2c:a1:22:09:
         03:91:b5:16:d6:d5:60:0b:a9:c2:8d:f4:6f:2c:1e:43:60:9d:
         a3:8b:5c:34:ef:89:e5:93:ba:93:f8:92:96:fb:d2:f4:4b:68:
         ca:0a:8c:58:d4:e2:cd:8e:e4:d7:90:1c:79:6f:c7:c2:61:ae:
         e7:52:07:70:e2:d9:b4:59:b2:73:c4:eb:f0:39:09:3f:b3:69:
         c7:2e:29:28:f5:a3:cd:fb:fd:2c:6b:b6:ad:de:f4:86:c4:e7:
         20:e2:fc:37:40:95:b2:11:27:48:3c:3e:1c:f9:bd:fe:d2:56:
         4d:a4:21:9c:85:eb:95:f1:bb:82:72:10:1c:d5:ff:eb:78:eb:
         c7:5c:5f:fd:ec:0c:07:66
```

Intermediate CA:

```
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number: 4096 (0x1000)
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C = IR, ST = Tehran, L = Tehran, O = SampleOrg, OU = Infrastructure Unit, CN = SampleOrg Root Certificate Authority, emailAddress = iu@sample.tld.com
        Validity
            Not Before: Jan  1 00:00:00 2018 GMT
            Not After : Jan  1 00:00:00 2048 GMT
        Subject: C = IR, ST = Tehran, O = SampleOrg, OU = Infrastructure Unit, CN = SampleOrg Intermediate Certificate Authority, emailAddress = iu@sample.tld.com
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                Public-Key: (4096 bit)
                Modulus:
                    00:ad:d4:fd:41:15:a9:9e:ee:ef:09:3f:3f:54:55:
                    b4:bc:eb:15:d7:e8:3f:3d:5c:6a:f1:6e:83:33:da:
                    98:d5:e8:f8:ee:a3:62:a0:5a:bd:e0:a6:b3:c3:a1:
                    2c:7f:80:32:e5:f7:a9:0d:e0:33:2f:16:03:bd:59:
                    f4:47:6c:2b:6a:c3:d1:bf:a8:98:d6:1a:25:48:45:
                    94:cc:f4:3b:00:fa:3a:62:5f:1d:2e:e6:e3:cc:f8:
                    4e:78:8e:0d:93:ca:46:d9:b8:fa:45:f6:0d:8a:9d:
                    47:47:fe:10:1f:54:69:8c:eb:5d:71:d5:69:dc:0f:
                    12:9f:7b:a1:3e:e4:79:77:0b:f1:f3:33:9f:a8:75:
                    5c:3c:1f:38:96:c9:6f:8e:f4:b7:33:d8:51:c7:43:
                    42:1f:8f:7f:99:8e:d7:16:e0:cd:c8:c5:71:ac:4e:
                    07:c5:59:88:c6:97:55:a8:1c:ef:c8:43:30:25:7d:
                    8d:00:65:ab:bc:6f:d4:54:48:3b:6f:d6:e6:6f:ee:
                    da:3a:93:73:c3:9c:79:27:3a:fe:01:8f:67:24:91:
                    d1:92:1b:76:90:df:68:2b:8f:74:06:bd:f3:e3:96:
                    31:90:23:31:49:e9:76:51:ee:8f:3e:85:78:3c:99:
                    e4:84:4d:1a:61:86:8f:22:d2:b6:90:96:f4:ca:52:
                    c5:c7:3c:c9:cc:bd:3f:6b:56:df:df:21:0d:b3:09:
                    05:12:b5:37:ee:61:26:a6:0d:21:d7:52:f9:49:0d:
                    17:8c:44:ab:72:82:0c:db:05:33:77:67:70:bb:94:
                    4c:db:07:97:58:77:f2:28:95:6e:97:d2:f3:6f:fa:
                    b9:58:23:e1:39:81:b0:c5:1c:df:7f:45:5c:b1:8f:
                    89:bd:b8:51:0d:6a:a5:db:9d:8f:97:05:2d:fa:3b:
                    15:04:67:b4:b4:b2:fd:fb:69:b9:d3:73:0c:56:79:
                    e2:67:7a:0d:f8:6d:60:04:48:99:c4:7e:6a:8c:b0:
                    73:d1:70:a7:7d:0b:c5:6d:40:72:fb:58:fd:b4:46:
                    8c:a0:40:87:1c:23:75:1a:8a:4b:40:3b:f3:38:50:
                    18:3d:99:d3:2d:81:87:dc:27:22:39:36:fd:59:b9:
                    03:63:1c:76:ff:a8:0b:7b:8f:de:ff:6d:59:18:3e:
                    e5:a9:0f:b8:2f:fd:52:5a:7a:e4:d4:03:4b:25:9a:
                    50:e5:1b:80:ce:ab:4a:04:0e:5f:a8:31:01:38:ea:
                    7f:1e:b5:0a:a5:65:f9:b0:c4:24:55:89:6e:8d:9e:
                    3a:cf:e9:9a:f5:8c:e1:1b:ee:29:2b:3b:16:51:d8:
                    77:fe:95:f9:15:d3:a9:61:30:bc:94:0a:7d:98:87:
                    d2:82:6d
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier:
                A7:6C:F7:40:34:DD:ED:0E:25:46:5D:16:65:4D:8F:ED:29:E8:5E:A7
            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier:
                keyid:4B:E6:00:6C:EB:DF:D8:4E:AB:EB:86:48:A2:8D:BB:18:09:C4:B4:6F

            X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
                CA:TRUE, pathlen:0
            X509v3 Key Usage: critical
                Digital Signature, Certificate Sign, CRL Sign
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
         d6:e5:f9:73:b4:50:98:ab:e9:6d:44:ef:4c:32:c4:88:bc:40:
         3d:1c:80:a2:04:09:da:e0:3d:9d:e2:c5:2b:1d:64:7b:84:81:
         4a:30:57:5a:c0:49:48:77:0b:c0:15:3e:cd:52:a9:d7:33:29:
         eb:95:ce:b1:a2:9b:7c:9d:ac:53:3d:a7:2c:b0:f1:a5:d2:81:
         c2:23:ea:bb:cd:e4:3f:e3:18:b4:70:6d:7d:23:1c:82:cc:01:
         67:f9:2e:a9:8a:9e:94:ac:aa:ef:a3:9c:66:13:e7:b9:11:2f:
         e5:52:c2:fe:92:f6:85:3f:3d:35:ad:57:15:d9:b8:19:b8:43:
         73:62:f0:5a:55:d6:f3:18:7c:9f:79:fc:11:b8:ac:f6:a7:14:
         e0:93:b1:9a:a8:42:1a:32:a8:36:43:87:b4:0d:76:2f:a5:ca:
         66:4b:c4:cf:58:ec:c2:75:1b:32:58:8c:be:cc:b8:4a:0c:bd:
         75:17:3d:b9:21:0b:e8:57:ea:84:92:e2:f8:d2:35:11:23:62:
         4d:64:d0:3b:db:d5:1c:14:03:a7:ff:d9:0a:64:eb:36:2d:79:
         6b:13:9f:d4:8d:08:01:86:83:10:a4:24:88:ea:6a:b4:75:07:
         ab:54:87:2a:b6:87:23:d9:b0:00:d4:ba:6a:1d:db:ab:49:f2:
         59:40:1f:6e:32:13:15:a7:40:3d:6a:22:24:12:4e:47:42:37:
         9c:27:f5:d2:93:3f:40:77:f8:c5:db:9b:f0:92:15:51:74:0d:
         5b:3c:f5:8b:a1:9c:39:f9:8b:41:3a:7b:57:00:31:d6:ca:e1:
         5f:ef:54:7d:69:ba:2f:ce:52:6f:77:f6:b6:2c:c8:d8:d5:bc:
         c9:99:d1:5a:5e:0f:b7:a4:24:09:58:07:af:bf:bc:1b:42:7b:
         9c:31:22:5a:b8:bb:24:24:af:5b:5e:f5:a3:48:b1:bb:5c:ed:
         86:87:70:af:10:6c:4e:34:d1:3e:2d:03:a8:4a:bf:67:1c:c6:
         61:18:b1:82:75:5b:a0:b2:2f:1e:8d:f8:6a:bd:47:53:94:b2:
         2c:93:74:c4:d6:d0:28:42:cf:4b:2f:61:81:86:42:53:ce:2f:
         6b:e2:8e:aa:bf:9e:d1:9d:6a:2a:d3:83:0b:c0:df:fc:19:f3:
         58:a0:ed:14:65:0f:87:9d:53:0b:d0:8d:fe:bb:97:8c:97:84:
         f8:d4:c0:2c:99:44:99:83:3f:6d:d4:e9:c5:b0:8d:b9:df:d7:
         5c:d3:fd:b9:90:36:1f:83:ba:53:dd:d0:8a:c6:a1:85:85:39:
         af:6b:9b:da:c3:1c:27:f3:3d:94:af:65:12:07:98:f5:5d:de:
         1a:d3:32:15:7a:d7:f7:63
```

Chain CA:

```
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number: 4096 (0x1000)
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C = IR, ST = Tehran, L = Tehran, O = SampleOrg, OU = Infrastructure Unit, CN = SampleOrg Root Certificate Authority, emailAddress = iu@sample.tld.com
        Validity
            Not Before: Jan  1 00:00:00 2018 GMT
            Not After : Jan  1 00:00:00 2048 GMT
        Subject: C = IR, ST = Tehran, O = SampleOrg, OU = Infrastructure Unit, CN = SampleOrg Intermediate Certificate Authority, emailAddress = iu@sample.tld.com
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                Public-Key: (4096 bit)
                Modulus:
                    00:ad:d4:fd:41:15:a9:9e:ee:ef:09:3f:3f:54:55:
                    b4:bc:eb:15:d7:e8:3f:3d:5c:6a:f1:6e:83:33:da:
                    98:d5:e8:f8:ee:a3:62:a0:5a:bd:e0:a6:b3:c3:a1:
                    2c:7f:80:32:e5:f7:a9:0d:e0:33:2f:16:03:bd:59:
                    f4:47:6c:2b:6a:c3:d1:bf:a8:98:d6:1a:25:48:45:
                    94:cc:f4:3b:00:fa:3a:62:5f:1d:2e:e6:e3:cc:f8:
                    4e:78:8e:0d:93:ca:46:d9:b8:fa:45:f6:0d:8a:9d:
                    47:47:fe:10:1f:54:69:8c:eb:5d:71:d5:69:dc:0f:
                    12:9f:7b:a1:3e:e4:79:77:0b:f1:f3:33:9f:a8:75:
                    5c:3c:1f:38:96:c9:6f:8e:f4:b7:33:d8:51:c7:43:
                    42:1f:8f:7f:99:8e:d7:16:e0:cd:c8:c5:71:ac:4e:
                    07:c5:59:88:c6:97:55:a8:1c:ef:c8:43:30:25:7d:
                    8d:00:65:ab:bc:6f:d4:54:48:3b:6f:d6:e6:6f:ee:
                    da:3a:93:73:c3:9c:79:27:3a:fe:01:8f:67:24:91:
                    d1:92:1b:76:90:df:68:2b:8f:74:06:bd:f3:e3:96:
                    31:90:23:31:49:e9:76:51:ee:8f:3e:85:78:3c:99:
                    e4:84:4d:1a:61:86:8f:22:d2:b6:90:96:f4:ca:52:
                    c5:c7:3c:c9:cc:bd:3f:6b:56:df:df:21:0d:b3:09:
                    05:12:b5:37:ee:61:26:a6:0d:21:d7:52:f9:49:0d:
                    17:8c:44:ab:72:82:0c:db:05:33:77:67:70:bb:94:
                    4c:db:07:97:58:77:f2:28:95:6e:97:d2:f3:6f:fa:
                    b9:58:23:e1:39:81:b0:c5:1c:df:7f:45:5c:b1:8f:
                    89:bd:b8:51:0d:6a:a5:db:9d:8f:97:05:2d:fa:3b:
                    15:04:67:b4:b4:b2:fd:fb:69:b9:d3:73:0c:56:79:
                    e2:67:7a:0d:f8:6d:60:04:48:99:c4:7e:6a:8c:b0:
                    73:d1:70:a7:7d:0b:c5:6d:40:72:fb:58:fd:b4:46:
                    8c:a0:40:87:1c:23:75:1a:8a:4b:40:3b:f3:38:50:
                    18:3d:99:d3:2d:81:87:dc:27:22:39:36:fd:59:b9:
                    03:63:1c:76:ff:a8:0b:7b:8f:de:ff:6d:59:18:3e:
                    e5:a9:0f:b8:2f:fd:52:5a:7a:e4:d4:03:4b:25:9a:
                    50:e5:1b:80:ce:ab:4a:04:0e:5f:a8:31:01:38:ea:
                    7f:1e:b5:0a:a5:65:f9:b0:c4:24:55:89:6e:8d:9e:
                    3a:cf:e9:9a:f5:8c:e1:1b:ee:29:2b:3b:16:51:d8:
                    77:fe:95:f9:15:d3:a9:61:30:bc:94:0a:7d:98:87:
                    d2:82:6d
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier:
                A7:6C:F7:40:34:DD:ED:0E:25:46:5D:16:65:4D:8F:ED:29:E8:5E:A7
            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier:
                keyid:4B:E6:00:6C:EB:DF:D8:4E:AB:EB:86:48:A2:8D:BB:18:09:C4:B4:6F

            X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
                CA:TRUE, pathlen:0
            X509v3 Key Usage: critical
                Digital Signature, Certificate Sign, CRL Sign
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
         d6:e5:f9:73:b4:50:98:ab:e9:6d:44:ef:4c:32:c4:88:bc:40:
         3d:1c:80:a2:04:09:da:e0:3d:9d:e2:c5:2b:1d:64:7b:84:81:
         4a:30:57:5a:c0:49:48:77:0b:c0:15:3e:cd:52:a9:d7:33:29:
         eb:95:ce:b1:a2:9b:7c:9d:ac:53:3d:a7:2c:b0:f1:a5:d2:81:
         c2:23:ea:bb:cd:e4:3f:e3:18:b4:70:6d:7d:23:1c:82:cc:01:
         67:f9:2e:a9:8a:9e:94:ac:aa:ef:a3:9c:66:13:e7:b9:11:2f:
         e5:52:c2:fe:92:f6:85:3f:3d:35:ad:57:15:d9:b8:19:b8:43:
         73:62:f0:5a:55:d6:f3:18:7c:9f:79:fc:11:b8:ac:f6:a7:14:
         e0:93:b1:9a:a8:42:1a:32:a8:36:43:87:b4:0d:76:2f:a5:ca:
         66:4b:c4:cf:58:ec:c2:75:1b:32:58:8c:be:cc:b8:4a:0c:bd:
         75:17:3d:b9:21:0b:e8:57:ea:84:92:e2:f8:d2:35:11:23:62:
         4d:64:d0:3b:db:d5:1c:14:03:a7:ff:d9:0a:64:eb:36:2d:79:
         6b:13:9f:d4:8d:08:01:86:83:10:a4:24:88:ea:6a:b4:75:07:
         ab:54:87:2a:b6:87:23:d9:b0:00:d4:ba:6a:1d:db:ab:49:f2:
         59:40:1f:6e:32:13:15:a7:40:3d:6a:22:24:12:4e:47:42:37:
         9c:27:f5:d2:93:3f:40:77:f8:c5:db:9b:f0:92:15:51:74:0d:
         5b:3c:f5:8b:a1:9c:39:f9:8b:41:3a:7b:57:00:31:d6:ca:e1:
         5f:ef:54:7d:69:ba:2f:ce:52:6f:77:f6:b6:2c:c8:d8:d5:bc:
         c9:99:d1:5a:5e:0f:b7:a4:24:09:58:07:af:bf:bc:1b:42:7b:
         9c:31:22:5a:b8:bb:24:24:af:5b:5e:f5:a3:48:b1:bb:5c:ed:
         86:87:70:af:10:6c:4e:34:d1:3e:2d:03:a8:4a:bf:67:1c:c6:
         61:18:b1:82:75:5b:a0:b2:2f:1e:8d:f8:6a:bd:47:53:94:b2:
         2c:93:74:c4:d6:d0:28:42:cf:4b:2f:61:81:86:42:53:ce:2f:
         6b:e2:8e:aa:bf:9e:d1:9d:6a:2a:d3:83:0b:c0:df:fc:19:f3:
         58:a0:ed:14:65:0f:87:9d:53:0b:d0:8d:fe:bb:97:8c:97:84:
         f8:d4:c0:2c:99:44:99:83:3f:6d:d4:e9:c5:b0:8d:b9:df:d7:
         5c:d3:fd:b9:90:36:1f:83:ba:53:dd:d0:8a:c6:a1:85:85:39:
         af:6b:9b:da:c3:1c:27:f3:3d:94:af:65:12:07:98:f5:5d:de:
         1a:d3:32:15:7a:d7:f7:63
```

Comment: `openssl x509 -noout -text -in <certificate file>` will give you a better view of your certificates than an image.  Copy/paste the output for all of your certificates into your question.

Comment: @garethTheRed added.

Comment: You only add the Root CA certificate to Firefox (or any other browser and/or Operating System).  All other certificates are added to the bundle end-entity first, followed by the CA that signed it, followed by the CA that signed that, all the way to the last Intermediate CA.  There's no need to add the Root CA here as that's installed in Firefox (or similar).  This bundle is then installed in your web-server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP server must has chain of `domain` and `intermediate` as chain of server side certificate.

```
cat certs/intermediate/certs/domain.cert.pem \ 
  certs/intermediate/certs/intermediate.cert.pem > webserver.cert.pem
```

This is not documented thou.

Comment: This works indeed. It's also described here: https://futurestud.io/tutorials/how-to-configure-nginx-ssl-certifcate-chain